# Unlimited image upload to server & name, categories, etc & multiple image path (1 row) to db

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I need a catalog script. I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find the right one for what I need. I need to upload multiple (unlimited) images to server while saving the product name, description, etc and mulitple image path in one row to db.

If possible, I would like to have unlimited image upload using this -->

```
    <input type="file" name="img[]" multiple>
```

**Image Upload**

- Files Max Size: 2048kb
- File Type: jpg/png/gif
- Upload Folder: [category]/image[random_number].jpg

**Database**

**Products**

- id
- product
- description
- category
- material
- color
- size
- style
- stock
- ws_price
- rt_price
- multiple_image_path

**Categories**

- cat_id
- parent_id
- category
- description

**Files**

- add_product.php
- view_product.php
- add_category.php
- db_connect.php
- upload.php
- .sql

If you know any scripts that are already set up for this or similar, and just need a little tweaking, it would be great if you can send me a link. :)

I had put together a file upload script before but it's pretty sloppy and I had to separate the upload files[]. Here's the old one from a long time ago:

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $random_digit = rand(0000,9999);
    $target = 'images/';

    $px = array();
    echo "<ul>";
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++ )
    {
       $px[$i] = "";
       $pic[$i+1] = ($_FILES["image" . ($i + 1)]["name"]);

       if (empty($pic[$i + 1]))
       {
          echo "<li>IMG $i + 1 EMPTY </li>";
       }
       else
       {
          $px[$i] = $random_digit . $pic[$i + 1];
          $px[$i] = preg_replace('/\s+/','_', $px[$i]);
          $px[$i] = str_replace('&', 'and', $px[$i]);
          $u = $target . $px[$i];
          $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image' . ($i + 1)]['tmp_name'], $u);
          echo "<li>IMG " . ($i + 1) . " Uploaded</li>";
       }
    }

    echo "</ul>";

     $itemnumber=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemnumber']); 
     $product=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product']); 
     $category=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']); 
     $color=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['color']); 
     $style=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['style']); 
     $material=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['material']); 
     $sizes=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sizes']); 
     $stocks=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stocks']); 
     $orders=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['orders']); 
     $wsprice=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wsprice']); 
     $rtprice=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rtprice']); 
     $profit=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['profit']); 
     $itemcode=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemcode']); 
     $suppliers=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['suppliers']); 
     $dc=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dc']); 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `items` (itemnumber, product, category, color, style, material, sizes, stocks, orders, wsprice, rtprice, profit, itemcode, suppliers, dc, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10) VALUES ('$itemnumber', '$product', '$category', '$color', '$style', '$material', '$sizes', '$stocks', '$orders', '$wsprice', '$rtprice', '$profit', '$itemcode', '$suppliers', '$dc', '$px[0]', '$px[1]', '$px[2]', '$px[3]', '$px[4]', '$px[5]', '$px[6]', '$px[7]', '$px[8]', '$px[9]')"; 

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>Item #: " . $itemnumber . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Product: " . $product . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Category: " . $category . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Style: " . $style . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Material: " . $material . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Sizes: " . $sizes . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Stocks: " . $stocks . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Orders: " . $orders . "</li>";
        echo "<li>WS Price: " . $wsprice . "</li>";
        echo "<li>RT Price: " . $rtprice . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Profit: " . $profit . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Item Code: " . $itemcode . "</li>";
        echo "<li>Suppliers: " . $suppliers . "</li>";
        echo "<li>DC: " . $dc . "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Entry Form

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" /> 

    <table border="0" cellpadding="3">
    <th colspan="3">Shop Item Entry</th>
    <tr><td>Item # <input type="text" name="itemnumber" size="27" value="01-00000">                  </td>
    <td>Product <input type="text" name="product" size="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Category <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  }
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);
    function finddepth($byid) {
    $re_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories where parent_id='$byid'");
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($re_query); //echo " Has children:".$num_rows."<br>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($re_query) > '0') {
while($recursive_rw=mysql_fetch_array($re_query)){
    $p=$recursive_rw['category_id'];
    $catnm=$recursive_rw['title'];
    $parent=$recursive_rw['parent_id'];
    $pre="- - ";
if($parent=="0") {
    ?>
<option><?php echo $catnm; ?></option>
    <?php
        } else {
    echo '<option value="'.$catnm.'">'.$pre.$catnm.'</option>' ;
        }
    finddepth($p);
        }//end while
    }//end if
    }//end of function
    ?><select name="category">
    <option values=" ">    </option>
    <?php finddepth(0); ?>
    </select>  
</td>
<td>Color <input type="text" name = "color"size="45">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Style <input type="text" name = "style" size="45"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td> Material <input type="text" name = "material" size="25"></td>
<td>
    Sizes <input type="text" name = "sizes" size="46">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Stocks                 <input type="text" name = "stocks" size="15">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Orders <input type="text" name = "orders" size="14">
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td  colspan="3">
    WS Price <input type="text" name = "wsprice" size="24">&nbsp;RT Price         <input type="text" name = "rtprice">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Profit <input type="text" name = "profit">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;DC: <input type="radio" name="dc" value="Yes"> Yes <input type="radio" name="dc" value="No" checked> No 
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td> Item Code: <input type="text" name = "itemcode" size="22"></td>
<td>Suppliers: <input type="text" name = "suppliers" size="100"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td colspan="3">
    <input size="25" name="image1" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image2" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image3" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image4" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image5" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image6" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image7" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image8" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image9" type="file" />
    <input size="25" name="image10" type="file" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"> 
     </form>
```

This one is working, but it's very cluttered with all the "upload files" thing and also if possible to add the feature of **unlimited image upload** instead of just 10 because some products have a lot more than 10 pictures needed. Anything can help so I would appreciate if you can just help me with these two files. Thank you!

*Can anyone tell me how to save multiple data (image path) in one row.

For example: img_path: "img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg"

```
   $img_path = implode(',', $_POST['img[]']); 

   INSERT INTO products (id, product, description, img_path)
   VALUES ('$id',$product','$description','$img_path')
```

Would this work? I haven't gotten around to test it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check out the jQuery file upload: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
For the 'basic' file upload, you pretty much just have to add the js-libs and a few callbacks. Very easy, checkout the examples for details. Plus you can easily later adopt cool progress bars etc. features that comes with it, should you need them.

For the server side code there is a pretty clean PHP-implementation here: https://github.com/Gargron/fileupload

Comment: Thanks~ I'll check those options soon.